# How can I check if an if statement inside a while loop has been satisfied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that, when given the terms of a sequence, prints an polynomial equation that can get those terms. I've added another feature to it, which mirrors the first part, in that it gives you the terms of the sequence after entering the equation.

So far, that has gone mostly well, but I've come across a problem when trying to implement another feature. If the user has already gotten the equation to a sequence, and they'd like to check perhaps some more terms of that sequence, I want them to be able to copy that equation if they'd like to, without doing it by hand, if that makes sense.

My attempt at this is as follows:

```
def func(var):
    if str(var) == "solve":
        terms = input("terms: ").split()

        ...
        coefs = []
        # code that defines the list coefs
        ...

        coefs = [a,b,c...]

        print(", ".join(coefs))

        copyeq = 1

    elif str(var) == "check":

        try:
            if copyeq == 1:
                if input("use coefficients as above?: ") == "yes":
                    checklist = coefs

                else:
                    return

            elif copyeq == 0:
                checklist = input("input coefficients: ").split()

            ...
            terms = []
            # code that defines the list terms
            ...

            terms = [p, q, r...]
            print(", ".join(term))

copyeq = 0

while 1:
    var = input("solve or check: ")
    func(var)
```

When I try to test this, it immediately jumps to the `elif copyeq == 0:` statement, meaning the value of 0 that I assigned to it in the `if var == "solve":` statement. Does anyone have any workarounds or solutions?

Edit: I intend for the user to be able to solve a sequence for its equation, or to check an equation for its sequence. If they choose to solve a sequence first, I want them to be able to check the equation that they just got as an answer. I thought that pointers could potentially solve my problem, but a quick search informed me that Python doesn't have pointers.

Comment: `copyeq == 1` will never be True since you are only setting `copyeq` to 1 in the outer **if** block. If the outer **if** statement is true, then the outer **elif** block will never been executed... since that's how **if-elif-else** statements work.

Comment: tetraxile does change copyeq in the `if var == 'solve'` block. I suspect there's more code we're not seeing (otherwise the `return` outside of a function would be a problem. @tetraxile can you provide more context?

Comment: I can try to add more context, yes

Comment: I would recommend you try to get your code to work first without the `while` loop, and also change the `elif` to `if`, test out your logic and make sure everything can be hit first before adding further complexity.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should review the logic of your program, it will go straight to the elif copyeq==0, because you are setting this variable to this value, so, every time the user picks check, the program goes to the elif.Maybe you could explain a little better how should the program behave?